# What's the Esperanto word for "blockchain"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

What's the Esperanto word for [*blockchain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_chain)? I am referring to the term used in cryptography.

Comment: Could you please explain what that word means? Even people with native English don't know it, as evident.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev It's a term in cryptocurrencies (such as Bitcoin) describing how transactions are stored.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev See [Blockchain on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain_(database)) and this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIVAluSL9SU).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would venture "blokĉeno" (from "bloko" and "ĉeno", literally "block" and "chain". Don't know if someone else came up with a different translation, though.

Answer (score 3):

> La **blokoĉeno** (angle blockchain) estas publika librotenista sistemo,
>   kiu gravuras bitmono-transakcioj. https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmono#Bloko.C4.89eno

Answer (score 2):

This was not a term I was familiar with, but I would go with the literal (and fairly transparent) translation "blokĉeno". A quick google search showed that it seems to have some traction.